# Is there any way to store credit/debit card detail for future use Using Braintree Android SDK

Tags: android, braintree

I am using `Braintree SDK` in my android app for `payments` and its working fine, But here is one problem it asks every time credit/debit card details. So my question is, is there any way to store credit/debit card detail for next time payments without asking again credit card detail for the same user.

Comment: You can't store credit card details. Neither in app nor in backend due to legal stuff. You have to use payment nonce, which is reusable.

Comment: Hi, Marius Kaunietis  so any other way to achieve this functionality..?

Comment: In app we did, we acquired payment nonce and sent it to backend. Whatever happens in backend, I do not know, but we surely did not have to enter details twice.

Comment: you have talk about this    *String strGetNonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();*

Comment: Sorry, but I can't tell you anything more. It's done in backend and I did the app. From app's point of view, I just send the nonce to backend when adding a card, and backend handles all the rest.

Comment: Ok Mr. Marius Kaunietis thanks for helping ..

Comment: I also try but facing same problem .how to manage with backend? @Dileep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can store credit cards and other payment methods in the [Braintree Payment Method Vault](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview) associated with your Braintree account. Payment methods are [associated directly to customer records](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer#payment_methods), and customers may have more than one payment method associated with them.

To present a customer with their payment methods during checkout, you have two options. If you're using a custom integration, you can [check the customer object for associated payment methods](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer#payment_methods) then [look up the details for each payment method in turn](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/find). If you're using the Drop-in, you have a simpler option.

The Drop-in form [automatically fetches a customer's payment methods](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in#client-side-implementation) when it is presented with a customer ID. To present it with a customer ID, first [generate a client token using a customer ID](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate#customer_id), then [use that client token to initialize the Drop-in](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in#customer-id).

```
ClientTokenRequest clientTokenRequest = new ClientTokenRequest()
    .customerId(aCustomerId);
String clientToken = gateway.clientToken().generate(clientTokenRequest);
```